# Proving an operator operator is compact on $L^p$, using Kolmogorov's theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, lebesgue-integral, convolution, compact-operators

I need to prove that the linear operator
$$B:L^p(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow L^p(\mathbb{R})$$
defined as follows for all $f \in L^p$ $B(f)=1_{[-L,L]}f*h$ such $h\in L^1$ and $L>0$.

$B $ is clearly linear and bounded (convolution property: $||f*h||_p\leq ||h||_1||f||_p)$.

So I need to prove that $B$ is compact (proves that $B(B(0,1)$ is relavely compact in $L^P$, with $B(0,1)$ is the unit ball in the space $L^p$) so I have tried to use Fréchet-Kolmogorov theorem so in order to prove that $B(B(0,1))$ is relatively compact I have to prove that:

$1-$ $B(B(0,1))$ is bounded.

$2-$ $\lim_{r\rightarrow +\infty}\int_{|x|>r}|g|^pdx=0$ for all $g \in B(B(0,1))$ uniformly

$3-$ $\lim_{a\rightarrow 0}||\tau_ag-g||_p=0$ for all $g \in B(B(0,1))$ uniformly

I proved that $ B(B(0,1))$ is bounded, due to the inequality mentionned before and we take $f$ such $||f||_p \leq 1$.

and the second point, is verifed because it's the rest of a convergent integral.

But I could not prove the third point.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy  no $g$ is not in $L^p$ there is $f\in B(0,1)$ such that $g=f*h$

Comment: I don't understand. You are saying that $B$ is a bounded operator from $L^{p}$ into itself. Since $g$ is in the range of $B$ it is in $L^{p}$. May be i have not understood your notattions.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy you’re right but the limit must be uniform on the set $B(B(0,1))$ so the theorem that you mentioned is not working

Comment: In that case you did not state 3) properly. 'for all $g \in B(B(0,1))$ does not mean uniformly  for all $g \in B(B(0,1))$. It only means for every fixed $g$.

Comment: Is it $(1_{[-L,L]}\cdot f) \ast h$ or $1_{[-L,L]} \cdot (f \ast h)$?

Comment: In your points 1) and 2), I guess that you need some uniformity with respect to the choice of $g$. You should clarify this.

Comment: @PhoemueX You're right I just did

Comment: @DanielFischer it's $1_{[-L,L]}(f*h)$